# Laravel 10 can't update data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

i can't update table data in laravel 10 with controller resource

my code:

```
// controller
    public function update(Request $request, string $id):RedirectResponse
    {
        //
        $input = $request->validate([
            'id'=>'required',
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
        ]);

        $accounting_group = AccountingGroup::findOrFail($id);
        $accounting_group->update($input);

        return redirect()->route('accounting_group.index')->with(['success' => 'Data telah disimpan']);
    }
```

```
<!-- route -->
Route::resource('accounting_group', AccountingGroupController::class)->except(['show']);
```

```
<!-- model -->
class AccountingGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'accounting_groups';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'description',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];

    public function transactionaccount(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TransactionAccount::class);
    }
}
```

```
<form method="post" class="mx-2 p-4" action="{{ route('accounting_group.update', $accounting_group->id) }}">
               @csrf
               @method('put')
          <div class="form-group">
               <label for="id">ID Akun</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="ID accounting..." value="{{ old('id', $accounting_group->id) }}">
          </div>
....
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
          </div>
          </form>
```

i didn't get eror display in laravel, i got refresh page where i clicked sumbit button and in mysql the data get no update

Comment: did you check the log in controller?

Comment: The `validate()` return the validated data, maybe there is no valid data in your `$input`, you can check by `dd($input);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow browser send input, you need to add you `name` attribute in your input for.

So you just need to add `name="id"` to your:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="ID accounting..." value="{{ old('id', $accounting_group->id) }}">
```

so your code should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" placeholder="ID accounting..." value="{{ old('id', $accounting_group->id) }}">
```

and don't forgot to add `name` attribute to other fields like `name="name"` and `name="description"`

Answer (score 1):

When you are using **Route::resource** and call the **show** or **update** method then you will get the requested ID in the record in the controller function it is called **property promotion**

Here I have enhanced your code

```
public function update(Request $request, AccountingGroup $accounting_group):RedirectResponse
{
    $input = $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',
        'description'=>'required',
    ]);

    $accounting_group->update($input->validated());

    return redirect()->route('accounting_group.index')->with(['success' => 'Data telah disimpan']);
}
```

> I have added the **AccountingGroup $accounting_group** in the
> argument. If this id record is not found then call the
> **ModelNotFoundException**

> And I have added the **$input->validated()** this method is only for
> returning the validated data, It's used for security purposes.